# JOLT transformation split object in array to two objects

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have array of objects and I want to split each object from this array into two objects
my input looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "amount": 30,
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "Approved",
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 123,
    "balance_after": 30.03,
    "transaction_id": 123
  },
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "Approved",
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 124,
    "balance_after": 70.03,
    "transaction_id": 124
  }
]
```

I am trying **Jolt Spec** like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[0].&",
      "@(1,timestamp)": "[1].timestamp",
      "@(1,user_id)": "[1].user_id",
      "@(1,balance_after)": "[1].balances.[0].balance",
      "@(1,currency)": "[1].balances.[0].currency",
      "#real_money": "[1].balances.[0].key",
      "#0": "[2].balances.[1].balance",
      "@(1,currency)": "[2].balances.[1].currency",
      "#bonus_money": "[2].balances.[1].key"
    }
  }
]
```

My expected result is

```json
[
  {
    "amount": 30,
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "Approved",
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 123,
    "balance_after": 30.03,
    "transaction_id": 123
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 123,
    "balances": [
      {
        "balance": 30.03,
        "currency": "USD",
        "key": "real_money"
      },
      {
        "balance": 0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "key": "bonus_money"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "Approved",
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 124,
    "balance_after": 70.03,
    "transaction_id": 124
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 124,
    "balances": [
      {
        "balance": 70.03,
        "currency": "USD",
        "key": "real_money"
      },
      {
        "balance": 0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "key": "bonus_money"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but I am receiving quite different result, this specification works correctly for this input:

```json
{
  "amount": 30,
  "currency": "USD",
  "status": "Approved",
  "timestamp": "1660117356314",
  "user_id": 123,
  "balance_after": 30.03,
  "transaction_id": 123
}
```

and I am receiving:

```json
[
  {
    "amount": 30,
    "currency": "USD",
    "status": "Approved",
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 123,
    "balance_after": 30.03,
    "transaction_id": 123
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1660117356314",
    "user_id": 123,
    "balances": [
      {
        "balance": 30.03,
        "key": "real_money"
      },
      {
        "currency": "USD",
        "balance": "0",
        "key": "bonus_money"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But currency does not appear for **REAL_MONEY** balance

Does anyone here have a solution how to achieve goal?

Comment: yes you are right, it is fixed, sorry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this when your input is a array.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].first.&",
        "timestamp": [
          "[#2].first.&",
          "[#2].second.timestamp"
        ],
        "user_id": [
          "[#2].first.&",
          "[#2].second..user_id"
        ],
        "balance_after": [
          "[#2].first.&",
          "[#2].second.balances[0].balance"
        ],
        "1,currency": [
          "[#2].first.&",
          "[#2].second.balances[0].currency"
        ],
        "#real_money": "[#2].second.balances[0].key",
        "#0": "[#2].second.balances[1].balance",
        "currency": [
          "[#2].first.&",
          "[#2].second.balances[1].currency"
        ],
        "#bonus_money": "[#2].second.balances[1].key"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "first|second": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQzC7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these specs

```json
[
  {
    // generate attributes which will be nested within "balances" array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "new_user_id": "=(@(1,user_id))",
        "new_timestamp": "=(@(1,timestamp))",
        "bal_balance": "=(@(1,balance_after))",
        "bal_currency": "=(@(1,currency))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // distinguish outermost objects and arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,user_id).&",
        "new_*": "n[&1].&(0,1)",
        "bal_*": "n[&1].balances[0].&(0,1)",
        "#real_money": "n[&1].balances[0].key", //static content
        "#0": "n[&1].balances[1].balance",      //static content
        "#USD": "n[&1].balances[1].currency",   //static content
        "#bonus_money": "n[&1].balances[1].key" //static content
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "n": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&1"
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "@": "o&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of key names of the outermost objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]